# How to paste HTML formatted text into one excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel cell(AF17) with HTML data in it.
I am needing to copy that into a cell in my report (A7)
I need the formatted text to stay in one cell.
Whenever I paste the data in, it separates itself into many cells vertically.
Here is my code at this point:

```
Private Sub Converter()

    Dim objData As DataObject ' Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim sSelAdd As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    sHTML = "<HTML>" & Range("AF3").Value & "</HTML>"

    Set objData = New DataObject
    objData.SetText sHTML
    objData.PutInClipboard
    Range("A7").Select

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

How do I get all the text to stay in the one cell?

Comment: what is the HTML?

Comment: <HTML><div>Here is the important text that we want to keep formatted.</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<ul>
 <ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li><font color="#2E75B5">Item</font></li>
  <li><font color="#2E75B5">Item</font></li>
 </ul>
</ul>

<ol>
 <ol>
  <ol>
   <li><font color="#C55A11">Item</font></li>
   <li><font color="#C55A11">Item2</font></li>
  </ol>
 </ol>
</ol>

<ul>
 <ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
 </ul>
</ul>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div></HTML>

Comment: So don't copy and paste it:  Can't this entire `Sub` be reduced to a one-liner like `Range("A7").Value = "<HTML>" & Range("AF3").Value & "</HTML>"`?

Comment: <HTML><div>Notes area.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>Lots of stuff here.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</HTML>

Comment: No, when you try that, the text literally puts in all of the html markup as well. We need it to format the text just as it does in a Rich Text field.

Answer (score -1):

There are few HTML tags that cause the content to continue in a different cell. The ones that I know are the `<br />` and `<tr>`, but I am not sure if the `<div>` tag is the reason in your HTML.

You can try removing the tags causing it, or try using [`style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"`](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1095-maintaining-line-breaks-in-an-html-excel-file.htm) on them (not sure if `<html style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;">` would work directly).

Another option can be to format the cell as you want it, save the file as .html or .mhtml, and check the generated HTML and CSS for that cell.